# Laravel/Blade Drop Down List - For more than one field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to use blade to display a dropdown list from table data. The problem I have, is that I want to display the results of **two** fields in the table concatenated, not just one.

So I want something to render something like;

```
<select id="agreement_type" name="agreement_type">
  <option value="1">Agreement Field 1 - Agreement Field 2</option>
  <option value="2">Agreement Field 1 - Agreement Field 2</option>
  <option value="4">Agreement Field 1 - Agreement Field 2</option>
</select>
```

My controller currently looks like this;

```
$agreements = Agreement::lists('agreement_type','id');

return View::make('client_agreements.create')
        ->with('agreements', $agreements);
```

My blade view currently looks like this;

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('agreement_type', 'Agreement type') }}
    {{ Form::select('agreement_type', $agreements) }}
</div>
```

I have tried to amend the view and controller in various ways to get the desired output. But can't get it to work.

I want to display `agreement_type` and `level` and have the `id` set as the value so I tried;

```
$agreements = Agreement::lists('agreement_type'.'level','id');
```

But this just displays `level` as the value and completely ignores `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the simplest method. Just use a `foreach` loop to build the options array:

```
$agreements = Agreement::all();
$agreementOptions = array();
foreach($agreements as $agreement){
    $agreementOptions[$agreement->id] = $agreement->agreement_type.' '.$agreement->level;
}
return View::make('client_agreements.create')
           ->with('agreements', $agreementOptions);
```

However you can also define an [attribute accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) in your model. You can use that to create new properties that can be accessed normal, but you can run logic to generate them (like combining to attributes)

```
public function getSelectOptionAttribute(){
    return $this->attributes['agreement_type'].' '.$this->attributes['level'];
}
```

And then you can use `lists`:

```
$agreements = Agreement::all()->lists('select_option', 'id');
```

(Laravel converts `SelectOption` (studly case) from the method name to `select_option` (snake case) for the attribute, so don't get confused by that)

Comment: I couldn't get the attribute accessor to work. `select_option doesn't exist`. My Laravel version is not that old, only a month or so. Your first suggestion worked well though so I will go with that for now. Thanks

Comment: When using `lists` directly it only works with DB fields because it does it using SQL. You can still use it though just call `all()` first. (Like in my updated answer)